# How can I make a python API to ping an ip address?

Tags: python, api, flask

So I have a discord bot and I want to add a feature where it pings an IP and tells you if it's online or not. I wanted to use an API in flask in case I use it for other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to ping using python, you can use the [pythonping](https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20usage%20of%20PythonPing%20is%20in%20a,ping%20function%20will%20always%20return%20a%20ResponseList%20object.) package.
You can also easily use it in flask.
A sample of the package at play is shown below.

```
import flask
from pythonping import ping

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return ping('127.0.0.1', verbose=True)

app.run()
```

Comment: Well yes I know but how would I create a flask API where you entered the URL with an IP Address and it pings it and responds with the status

Comment: I have updated the code, such a setup can help with what you are saying.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working on bugs but your solution had helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `requests` package to perform this operation as follows:

```
import requests
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
is_up = requests.get(url).status_code == 200
print(f'{url}, up_status={is_up}')
```